# How to select Distinct on inner join?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can help me, I have something problem about query select distinct,  :

My table

```
table_pemesan 
id_pms

table_pesan
no_psn
id_pms

table_dpesan
no_psn
```

My query mysql

```
select pm.id_pms,   
       pm.nama, 
       pm.date_create,
       ps.no_psn,
       ps.status, 
       dps.no_dpsn            
FROM  pemesan as pm
INNER JOIN pesan ps on ps.id_pms=pm.id_pms 
INNER JOIN dpesan dps on dps.no_psn=ps.no_psn 
ORDER BY pm.id_pms ASC
```

//output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_pms] => 1
            [nama] => Isnan
            [date_create] => 2014-05-28 23:54:54
            [no_psn] => 1
            [status] => sedang diproses
            [no_dpsn] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_pms] => 1
            [nama] => Isnan
            [date_create] => 2014-05-28 23:54:54
            [no_psn] => 1
            [status] => sedang diproses
            [no_dpsn] => 2
        )

)
```

the array index 0 & 1 the same data, and my question how to distinct the query? thanks b4, sorry my english not good..

Comment: Have you used DISTINCT?

Comment: It's not the same. no_dpsn holds two different values !?!?!

Comment: ah @Strawberry you are right I did not notice while I typed , let me delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT pm.id_pms, pm.nama, pm.date_create, ps.no_psn, ps.status, dps.no_dpsn
FROM  pemesan as pm
INNER JOIN pesan ps on ps.id_pms=pm.id_pms 
INNER JOIN dpesan dps on dps.no_psn=ps.no_psn 
ORDER BY pm.id_pms ASC
```